# Having an awful time trying to get OpenCV to work

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to use python/opencv to calculate the distance from a camera to an object: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/

I am on an ubuntu box. I installed numpy super easily using pip, but am having a hell of a time trying to get opencv to work. I went through this article to install it from source: http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Everything seems like it installed correctly... when I run `dpkg -l | grep libopencv` I get

`ii  libopencv-calib3d2.4:amd64           2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision Camera Calibration library
ii  libopencv-contrib2.4:amd64           2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision contrib library
ii  libopencv-core2.4:amd64              2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision core library
ii  libopencv-features2d2.4:amd64        2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision Feature Detection and Descriptor Extraction library
ii  libopencv-flann2.4:amd64             2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision Clustering and Search in Multi-Dimensional spaces library
ii  libopencv-highgui2.4:amd64           2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision High-level GUI and Media I/O library
ii  libopencv-imgproc2.4:amd64           2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision Image Processing library
ii  libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64            2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision legacy library
ii  libopencv-ml2.4:amd64                2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision Machine Learning library
ii  libopencv-objdetect2.4:amd64         2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision Object Detection library
ii  libopencv-photo2.4:amd64             2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision computational photography library
ii  libopencv-video2.4:amd64             2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1                       amd64        computer vision Video analysis library`

But when I downloaded the source code and ran the code from the first link, I get this error:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (step[dims-1] == (size_t)CV_ELEM_SIZE(flags)) in create, file /home/nitrous/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 236
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distance_to_camera.py", line 41, in <module>
    marker = find_marker(image)
  File "distance_to_camera.py", line 16, in find_marker
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.error: /home/nitrous/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:236: error: (-215) step[dims-1] == (size_t)CV_ELEM_SIZE(flags) in function create`

Answer (score 0):

Use your package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Change it to python3-opencv if you want the Python3 version. It will install all dependencies, including python-numpy, for you.

Please don't use pip for the global packages that are in aptitude, these are handled by the system and YMMV if you use pip (as shown above). If you would like to use pip, create a virtualenv to install individual packages.

For any future packages, to check if the package is available in aptitude, simply run:

```
apt-cache search python-{package}
```

or

```
apt-cache search python3-{package}
```

This will let you know if there are any installation candidates. If a -dev version of the package is available, you may also want to install it.

Comment: I have done that, here are the results ```sudo apt-get install python-opencv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-opencv is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded```

Comment: Did you try: `import cv2` (this imports Open CV2). This likely means your module is already installed.

Comment: Yes, on line 2 of the code I'm using, I have this: `import cv2`

Comment: Is that traceback above from trying to import CV2 from the aptitude installer? Or is it from a traceback in the compiled version?

Comment: It's from when I try to run the python file in the first link.

Comment: Looks like a local installation is overriding your aptitude install. I would remove the entire `/home/nitrous/opencv-2.4.9/` directory and try to import it again, so the aptitude package can be imported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110194/discussion-between-alexander-huszagh-and-joshua-terrill).